# oci_execute(): ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments

Tags: php, html, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a problem with calling my stored procedure from Oracle SQL Developer to php. The stored procedure I'm trying to call is supposed to update my table but it returns the error as shown in title which is **ORA-06550** and does not update anything in my table according to the data I've entered as input in the form. The stored procedure is called in the file `updatepatient.php` as action for the form `updatepet.html`. The *patient_regdate* column is triggered which is why I did not include them in the procedure.

Here is the code of my table and stored procedure:

```
create table patient
(
patient_id varchar(15) primary key,
patient_name varchar(100),
patient_bdate date,
patient_breed varchar(50),
patient_gender varchar(100),
owner_name varchar(50),
owner_contact int,
patient_regdate date
);
```

```
create or replace procedure updatepatientpro(a in varchar, b in varchar, c in date, d in varchar, e in varchar, f varchar, g in int)
as
begin
    update patient
    set patient_name=b, patient_bdate=c, patient_breed=d, patient_gender=e, owner_name=f, owner_contact=g  
    where patient_id = a;
end;
/

declare 
a varchar(15);
b varchar(100);
c date;
d varchar(50);
e varchar(1);
f varchar(50);
g int;
begin
a := 'P100';
b := 'Lana';
c := '10-JUN-2018';
d := 'Samoyed';
e := 'M';
f := 'Melinda Oak';
g := '01234567890';
updatepatientpro(a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
end;
/
```

Here is the code of my php file, `updatepatient.php`:

```
$name = $_POST['PATIENT_NAME'];
$bdate = $_POST['PATIENT_BDATE']; 
$breed = $_POST['PATIENT_BREED'];
$gender = $_POST['PATIENT_GENDER'];
$owname = $_POST['OWNER_NAME'];
$contact = $_POST['OWNER_CONTACT'];


    $query1 = 'BEGIN UPDATEPATIENTPRO(:PATIENT_NAME, :PATIENT_BDATE, :PATIENT_BREED, :PATIENT_GENDER, :OWNER_NAME, :OWNER_CONTACT);END;';
    $result = oci_parse($connection, $query1);

    oci_bind_by_name($result, ':PATIENT_NAME', $name);
    oci_bind_by_name($result, ':PATIENT_BDATE', $bdate);
    oci_bind_by_name($result, ':PATIENT_BREED', $breed);
    oci_bind_by_name($result, ':PATIENT_GENDER', $gender);
    oci_bind_by_name($result, ':OWNER_NAME', $owname);
    oci_bind_by_name($result, ':OWNER_CONTACT', $contact);

    oci_execute($result);

    if (oci_fetch($result)==0) 
    {
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.alert('Updated Successfully!');</script>";
    }

    else
    {
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.alert('Update Failed');</script>";
    }
```

And the code of my form to update in html, `updatepet.html`:

```
<form class="" action="updatepatient.php" method="post" id="updatepatient"> <p>
                    Pet's ID: <input type="text" name="PATIENT_ID" placeholder="Patient's ID" class="inputtxt" required>
                    Pet's Name: <input type="text" name="PATIENT_NAME" placeholder="Patient's Name" class="inputtxt" >
                    Pet's Date of Birth (dd-mm-yy): <input type="text" name="PATIENT_BDATE" placeholder="DOB" class="inputtxt" >
                    Pet's Breed: <input type="text" name="PATIENT_BREED" placeholder="Breed" class="inputtxt" >
                    Gender: <p><select name="PATIENT_GENDER" class="inputtxt">
                            <option value="F">F</option>
                            <option value="M">M</option>
                            </select> <p>
                    Owner's Name: <input type="text" name="OWNER_NAME" placeholder="Owner's Name" class="inputtxt" >
                    Owner's Contact: <input type="text" name="OWNER_CONTACT" placeholder="Owner's Contact" class="inputtxt" >
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="subbtn">
                    </form>
```

Comment: Your procedure takes 7 arguments.  You are calling `oci_bind_by_name` 6 times so you're only passing 6 parameters.  Thus, you get the error that the number of parameters passed doesn't match the number of parameters expected.  It looks like you've forgotten to pass in the `patient_id`

Comment: Oh, got it! Thank you!! You're a lifesaver :)

Comment: Note that it's generally easier to spot this sort of thing if you name things consistently-- parameters `a`, `b`, and `c` are a lot harder to deal with than `p_patient_id`, `p_patient_name`, etc. where you can easily go parameter by parameter to make sure you have everything.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll keep that in mind. Have a great one!

Comment: Feel free to delete the question

Comment: Next time please search for `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments`